# Difference in Bit-depth in Satellite Images

Tags: satellite, bit-depth

I have DMSP/OLS and VIIRS satellite images. For the 1st image the bit depth is 8, for the 2nd image is 32. I want to make intercalibration between those images. Will it cause a problem due to difference in the bit of the images?

Answer (score 1):

No significant issues with it. DMSP/OLS is less accurate than VIIRS, but that will only impact the accuracy of the correlation, not the overall intercalibration.

Comment: I would like to make resampling (viirs to ols res). what is the best method to use (average, median, mode etc)?

Comment: Try all of them and see which one performs the best.